# Error in Microsoft Power Automate while exporting the App

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, flow, power-automate, powerapp

I am getting this below error while exporting Power apps Canvas app. I know it's related to some permissions but I am the co-owner of this app. Do I miss anything on this?

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Error:

> Could not find flow 'af63f417-0397-44ea-8244-0f7719475352'. The caller with object id '64e6b4c0-80b9-414d-b56c-5406e98ad97e' does not have permission for connection '2157a29e-a6d1-41f6-8a78-4c8ff09f24bb' under API 'shared_logicflows'.

Comment: Are you calling any power automate flow in your app? If yes, did you create that flow & all the connections are assigned with your user account?

Comment: yes powerautomate is calling from powerapps , so the problem is i don't have access for that flow which is calling from powerapps?

Comment: Yes exactly. Try exporting app with user account which has permissions on both app & flow.